# keep option selected after a refresh

Tags: html

I have a list of people sorted by 2 parameters that I insert in a select.

How can, when someone select a parameter, maintain this one selected when he refresh or change/return on the page?

I see some issues on some post over the internet, but most of them use JQuery, and I don't want to use it.

The code is like this:

```
<select name="idactivity_contact[]" id="_activity" multiple="multiple" size="10" style="width:150px;">
    <option disabled="disabled" style="background-color:#dddddd;font-weight:bold;">Shipbroking</option>
    <option value="1">Newbuilding</option>
    <option value="2">Sales and Purchase</option>
    <option value="3">Bulk</option>
</select>
```

The code is generated in PHP actyally manually, but i will do a function later

Comment: How is the html generated? Is there any server side codE?

Comment: You will need cookies

Comment: So please edit your question. Having php on the server side is an important fact. Do not expect us to help you to solve the issue if we don't have all the cards in the hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use `javascript` and `localStorage`:

```
document.getElementById("_activity").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedtem', document.getElementById("_activity").value);
}

if (localStorage.getItem('item')) {
    document.getElementById("selectedtem").options[localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')].selected = true;
}​
```

You can also use `cookies` or `session` in your sever side as well.

Comment: Can usage of localStorage be disabled, as users can with cookies?

Comment: @Felix: And you may write `session/session cookies` as sessions needs cookies, so no one get the impression it is either.

Answer (score 0):

Most direct approach would be to store the values of $_POST[] in $_SESSION[].

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that the person who created the page don't use the $_SESSION:/