# Keep option after a refresh in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to keep the selected option in HTML after doing a refresh using local storage. I followed the example mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192640/keep-option-selected-after-a-refresh)
Below is my code.

```js
document.getElementById("interface-output").onchange = function() {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedtem', document.getElementById("interface-output").value);
};

if (localStorage.getItem('item')) {
  document.getElementById("selectedtem").options[localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')].selected = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="ott-redirect-interface-selector">
  <label>Output Interface</label><br>
  <select id="interface-output" class="browser-default">
    <option value="select">Select an interface</option>
    <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
    <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this setting doesn't preserve the selected option after a refresh. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Are you running the JS after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: I'm extending an existing code base. Not too sure

Comment: `getElementById("selectedtem")` is looking for an `id` that doesn't exist in your HTML. Did you mean `getElementById("interface-output")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="row" id="ott-redirect-interface-selector">
      <label>Output Interface</label><br>
      <select id="interface-output" class="browser-default">
        <option id="select" value="select">Select an interface</option>
        <option id="eth0" value="eth0">eth0</option>
        <option id="eth1" value="eth1">eth1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('interface-output').onchange = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedtem', document.getElementById('interface-output').value);
      };

      if (localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')) {
        document.getElementById('interface-output').options[localStorage.getItem('selectedtem')].selected = true;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried so but it gives me this error when I do the refresh:
uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'options' of null

Comment: I added an id for select, too. Can you copy & paste all of this in a new file and open it with your browser?

Comment: I have a php form containing this dropdown, Now the form is not getting submitted. Any possible reason?